# Swagger2 ui not accessbile

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, swagger

I am using Swagger in a Spring boot application,
I somehow can access most of Swagger's endpoints such as `/v2/api-docs`, `/swagger-resources` but I can't figure out why `/swagger-ui.html` is not accessible.

I am using these dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

here is my Swagger Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("app.controllers"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here is the interesting part of the log:

```
2017-12-27 14:12:09.896 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /springfox/swagger-ui.html at position 12 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.896 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /springfox/swagger-ui.html at position 13 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/springfox/swagger-ui.html'; against '/'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/springfox/swagger-ui.html'; against '/v2/api-docs'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/springfox/swagger-ui.html'; against '/configuration/ui'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/springfox/swagger-ui.html'; against '/swagger-resources'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/springfox/swagger-ui.html'; against '/configuration/security'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/springfox/swagger-ui.html'; against '/swagger-ui.html'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/springfox/swagger-ui.html'; against '/webjars/**'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /springfox/swagger-ui.html' doesn't match 'POST /login
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /springfox/swagger-ui.html; Attributes: [authenticated]
2017-12-27 14:12:09.897 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8f3b828e: Principal: 0001; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER
2017-12-27 14:12:09.903 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@45d0a23, returned: 1
2017-12-27 14:12:09.903 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2017-12-27 14:12:09.903 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2017-12-27 14:12:09.903 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /springfox/swagger-ui.html reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2017-12-27 14:12:09.904 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/springfox/swagger-ui.html]
2017-12-27 14:12:09.906 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /springfox/swagger-ui.html
2017-12-27 14:12:09.919 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2017-12-27 14:12:09.920 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2017-12-27 14:12:09.920 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
2017-12-27 14:12:09.920  WARN 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported
2017-12-27 14:12:09.921 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@8f3b828e: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@8f3b828e: Principal: 0001; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3bcccd7c
2017-12-27 14:12:09.921 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-12-27 14:12:09.921 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2017-12-27 14:12:09.922 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.923 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2017-12-27 14:12:09.923 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2017-12-27 14:12:09.923 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@203209de
2017-12-27 14:12:09.923 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
2017-12-27 14:12:09.928 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2017-12-27 14:12:09.928 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2017-12-27 14:12:09.930 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity io.xhub.secusid.exception.SecusidErrorHandler.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2017-12-27 14:12:09.930 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'secusidErrorHandler'
2017-12-27 14:12:09.930 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2017-12-27 14:12:09.943 DEBUG 10212 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] i.x.s.exception.SecusidErrorHandler      : Request method 'GET' not supported

org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Comment: you have swagger-ui dependency in your pom right?

Comment: yes I do, like I said other endpoints such as v2/api-docs work

Comment: `v2/api-docs` comes from base swagger, `/swagger-ui.html` comes from a different dependency. You have both? Show us your dependency list, like your pom.xml.

Comment: yes, springfox-swagger-ui, I have that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a class like this

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    // Make Swagger meta-data available via <baseURL>/v2/api-docs/
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    // Make Swagger UI available via <baseURL>/swagger-ui.html
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using Spring boot, so it should do it,tried it anyway that didn't work

Comment: which version of swagger are you using?

Comment: swagger and swagger-ui version is 2.4.0

Comment: Thats nice. But this is some sort of a bug in swagger-ui I believe. Actually, swagger-ui should work without any configuration out of the box. But sometimes(may be because of other dependencies in the project), it doesn't work and we need to explicitly do it like this