# Hybris + swagger integration swagger-ui.html UnknownResourceError

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to integrate swagger in MYcommercewebservices.
I read post and done all steps listed on it, but still having this error.

https://localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices/v2/v2/api-docs working fine. https://localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices/v2/swagger-ui.html - return UnknownResourceError.

Furthermore - if I navigate to https://localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices/swagger-ui.html (without 'v2') it'll show me this message (javascript alert):

> Unable to infer base URL. This is common when using dynamic servlet
>   registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base URL is
>   the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if
>   the API is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the
>   base URL is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location
>   manually:

I found this controller, and probably part of the problem was in it because it was throwing an exception when I navigated to https://localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices/v2/swagger-ui.html

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController
{
    @RequestMapping
    public void defaultRequest(final HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        throw new UnknownResourceException("There is no resource for path " + YSanitizer.sanitize(request.getRequestURI()));
    }
}
```

Now I disabled controller, but still having the same exception, but now it's in json format instead of .xml.

Thank you!

Comment: are you able to reach http://localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices/v2/api-docs  ?

Comment: I'm not. But v2/v2 is the correct path for api-docs - one for services version and another for api-docs version(at least all sources on hybris help saying this).

Comment: so is api-docs available at  localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices/v2/v2/api-docs  ?

Comment: yes, it is available. Hybris sees api urls and documentation, but UI(swagger-ui.html  page) not working.

Comment: see, if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993752/swagger2-ui-not-accessbile/47993965?noredirect=1#comment82981497_47993965

Comment: Still not working... resource not found. Most weird thing here I can't understand - it returns swagger-ui.html if I go to https://localhost:9002/mycommercewebservices/swagger-ui.html but there js alert. And when I go /v2/swagger-ui.html it can't find it. Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was in DefaultController (in MYcommercewebservices)

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController
{
    @RequestMapping
    public void defaultRequest(final HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        throw new UnknownResourceException("There is no resource for path " + YSanitizer.sanitize(request.getRequestURI()));
    }
}
```

It was catching my request and throwing the exception.
When I disabled this controller, I continued to receive an exception, but now it was in json format(before it was in xml).

Than I added this to springmvc-v2-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/>
```

Now UI works fine!

Also there were another manipulation before all this, but you can find them in hybris experts(quite big post).